# Error when trying to implement Holt-Winters Exponential Smoothing in Pyspark

Tags: python, statsmodels, holtwinters

I am trying to perform Holt-Winters Exponential Smoothing on my dataset FinalModel which has `Date` as an index and `Crimecount` column in addition to other columns. I only want to forecast the `CrimeCount` column but I am getting the following error:

`ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'double' but got 'long long'`

My code:

```
df = FinalModel.copy()
train, test = FinalModel.iloc[:85, 18], df.iloc[85:, 18]
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters import ExponentialSmoothing

df.index.freq = 'MS'
model = ExponentialSmoothing(train.astype(np.int64), seasonal='mul', seasonal_periods=12).fit()
pred = model.predict(start=test.index[0], end=test.index[-1])
plt.plot(train.index, train, label='Train')
plt.plot(test.index, test, label='Test')
plt.plot(pred.index, pred, label='Holt-Winters')
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

Comment: Try `model = ExponentialSmoothing(train.astype('<f8'), seasonal='mul', seasonal_periods=12).fit()`, i.e. instead of int type convert to float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that the input values should be `doubles`, but instead `long` types were received. Forcing the input values to be numpy floats instead of numpy ints will do the trick:

```
df = FinalModel.copy()
train, test = FinalModel.iloc[:85, 18], df.iloc[85:, 18]
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters import ExponentialSmoothing

df.index.freq = 'MS'
model = ExponentialSmoothing(train.astype('<f8'), seasonal='mul', seasonal_periods=12).fit()
pred = model.predict(start=test.index[0], end=test.index[-1])
plt.plot(train.index, train, label='Train')
plt.plot(test.index, test, label='Test')
plt.plot(pred.index, pred, label='Holt-Winters')
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

Usually most statistical models both from `statsmodels` and `sklearn` assume the input values are floats. Most of these methods do the conversion automatically for you, but it seems that the ExponentialSmoothing does not. Nevertheless it is a good habit to cast the input values to floats for consistency.